# Can't update OpenSSL on Centos 6.4

Tags: centos, openssl

I've got a Centos 6.4 system that I'm trying to patch OpenSSL for.  Currently, yum reports "1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4" and openssl version shows "1.0.1e-fips".  On my Ubuntu machines, I was able to update openssl very easily with apt, but if I try "yum update openssl" (or even just "yum update") I get the response "No Packages marked for Update".  This seems very unlikely to me.

How can I update this machine?

Update:

```
$ sudo python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb=yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.yumvar, width=1)'
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin
Loading "product-id" plugin
Loading "refresh-packagekit" plugin
Not loading "subscription-manager" plugin, as it is disabled
Config time: 0.042
Running "init" handler for "rhnplugin" plugin
There was an error communicating with RHN.
RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.
Error communicating with server. The message was:
Name or service not known
{'arch': 'ia32e',
 'basearch': 'x86_64',
 'releasever': '6Workstation',
 'uuid': '<< something valid looking >>'}
```

After I add a repo here, it made a huge series of updates.  Unfortunately, even after restart:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

And `yum update openssl` still says "No Packages marked for Update", with `yum list openssl` returning

```
Installed Packages
openssl.x86_64                    1.0.1e-42.el6_7.4                     @updates
Available Packages
openssl.i686                      1.0.1e-42.el6_7.4                     updates
```

Comment: Add the content of `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` to your question.

Comment: And while you're at it, the output of the following command: `python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.yumvar, width=1)'`

Comment: looks to me like your CentOS server is trying (and failing) to use the RedHat Network?

Answer (score 2):

You do not appear to have any CentOS repo's setup, or at least none that work.  You can confirm this by running `yum repolist`.  If no entries appear under 'repo id' and/or 'repo name' then definitely no repos setup.

One simple way to correct the problem is to use `yum-config-manager --add-repo=<CentOS repo>`.  That automatically creates a config file under /etc/yum.repos.d/

To get an official CentOS repo, I believe this page would be helpful: https://wiki.centos.org/Download

EDIT:
This may be a more helpful URL: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-maintenance.html

That explains how to install the "fastest mirror" RPM which would choose a mirror for you, assuming you have connectivity to the internet.

Comment: Thanks.  Even after I've done this though, it still won't update openssl.

Comment: Since you are running CentOS 6.4, you are probably already running the latest available OpenSSL version for 6.4.  You have the option to update to CentOS 6.8.  Simply do a `yum update` and follow the prompts.

Comment: Maybe I'm already on 6.8 then?  How do I check?

Answer (score 0):

`yum update openssl` issue, I was getting this following error while trying to update openssl.

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
There was an error communicating with RHN.
RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.
Error communicating with server. The message was:

Error Class Code: 6001
Error Class Info:
RHN is in the process of being decommissioned and systems are no longer able to receive updates or make use of any RHN services.
Please see https://access.redhat.com/articles/2979901 for more info.

Setting up Update Process
Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://mirrors.iuscommunity.org/mirrorlist?repo=ius-el6&arch=x86_64&protocol=http error was
14: Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: ius. Please verify its path and try again.
```

After few RND I got the solution for error code 6001. Here is the summery, which resolved that issue:

```
mv /etc/yum.repos.d/* /tmp/
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
yum clean all
yum repolist
yum update openssl
yum list installed openssl
```